# Position Div below window height

Tags: jquery, html, css

Lets see below example

```
<div>Main Content<br><br>Main Content which fills windows height</div>
<div id="belowcontent">Content to be show below the windows height</div>
```

I tried something like below

```
$("#belowcontent").css("margin-top", $(window).height());
```

But problem here is the div is using the height from previous DIV,Not the browser top.I tried position absolute too.Still not working.

P.s: If its pure CSS method , thats advantage

Comment: `margin-top: 100vh` ?

Comment: So, you're trying to make the 'main content' div fullscreen, and the user should have to scroll down to see `#belowcontent`, is that right?

Comment: `$('#belowcontent').css('top', $(window).height());`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : exactly , you are right

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m4j0jxhw/, is that what you want ?

Comment: @PardeepDhingra : Is it possible via only css?

Comment: its possible with css if height of your top div is `100%`

Comment: @SimonM. : For some reason your solution is pushing the div to bottom of the page in my development project

Answer (score 4):

## Absolute positioning

You could use `absolute` positioning with a `top` declaration. In this case I've set `top` to `100vh` to place it below the screen height.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightgray;
}
.main {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
#belowcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Main Content
  <br>
  <br>Main Content which fills windows height</div>
<div id="belowcontent">Content to be show below the windows height</div>
```

---

## Relative Positioning

If you don't want to use positioning, you may be able to use (instead) a min-height property on your `main` div:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
#belowcontent {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Main Content
  <br>
  <br>Main Content which fills windows height</div>
<div id="belowcontent">Content to be show below the windows height</div>
```

Comment: another solution would be giving the `.main` div `width: 100vw; height: 100vh` and the `#belowcontent` could be relative that way, no need for absolute

Comment: That's definitely true. Although I would be reluctant to use a set height, but possibly a min-height declaration. Will update.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida: Although setting a width is redundant since div's are `display:block` by default.

Comment: can it be full width ? certain things are not working https://jsfiddle.net/m4j0jxhw/1/ , for example text-align.

Comment: @Vishnu: In that case, then yes, you'd need to add a `width:100%` to your belowcontent div: https://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/m4j0jxhw/3/

Comment: I tried adding 100% , but its overflowing and not responsive..see bottom of https://pandatracking.com/ for example

Comment: @Vishnu: I failed to add the `left:0` property in my example. Adding that should solve your issue.

Comment: How to set min height ? If screen height is small , its overlapping the top div.